# Looking for .net logger that would save output as html page

Tags: .net, logging, documentation-generation

Is there any .net logger that would log events and write logs to html page or maybe any logger that stores logs to database or to file and then generates html page from it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not aware of any complete solution as you ask for; log parsing can be very specific because in logging frameworks like `Log4Net` or `NLog` you can define what you log and how your logs look like.

I would use `Log4Net` and store to database then make your ASP.NET application which loads most recent entries from that database into a gridView, just to start, then if you imagine to add paging, sorting and filtering to that asp.net application you have another whole project to take care of :)

there are also Log4Net appenders which send out HTML emails, see here for an example: http://modelus.com/Products/Log4NetExtensions.aspx you can have a look at the sources and imagine to write your own HTML publisher appender if you really want to go this way...